# (Rolling) Evaluation of whole forecast horizon

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have a time series with about 200 to 250 observations (depending on the cross-section) and I do different rolling forecasts. The maximum forecast horizon is 20. I would like to evaluate the forecast for the whole horizon (not just x-steps ahead) at each point in time.

Since the literature basically always only evaluates x-steps ahead I am not really sure what the best way to do that would be. My current idea is to calculate different indicators (like RSME) for the whole horizon and take the average in the end.

As the training set increases the forecast accuracy should also increase, and therefore I am not sure whether it is a good idea to use the average (or median) or not. Any alternative ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole horizon"?

Comment: At each point in time I would like to evaluate the forecasts for t+1, t+2, ... t+20 at the same time. I do the forecast today, evaluate each period forecasted and do the same tomorrow. Usually one only gets an indicator for the quality of the forecast for x-periods ahead, but not an indicator for each value forecasted at a given day. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I think I understand now. It could help to define your loss function explicitly to find out how you combine the different forecast horizons together.

Comment: I kinda saw this question coming. Well, I don't have one. That's the reason why I asked for ideas (that make sense/are used). But I am aware of the fact that each "approach" assumes some sort of loss function (and certain preferences).